# will my installer crash if my screen goes to sleep

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, crash

Why does my ubuntu installer keep crashing, My computer has almost 1.5 gigs of memory and a 2.8 ghz processor. its a pretty fast computer. I have never had problems with it in the past. I dont know what else to try. I have continued to try reinstalling it over and over off of my usb thumb drive. Will the installer crash if my screen goes to sleep?

Comment: It **most certainly** has nothing to with your screen going to sleep. Please [click here](http://askubuntu.com/posts/360595/edit) and tell us more about those crashes. When do they occur? Always at the same point? Is there an error message you can give us in full length? How do you know it crashed?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed (and reinstalled) ubuntu many times due to my earlier (and somewhat present) noobiness with ubuntu and I have left it running many times and came back to see the screen asleep but ubuntu did not crash. I have installed ubuntu on a laptop and the same thing happened. Maybe you are not installing it correctly. A really good walkthrough can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).